# Multi conditional probability question

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-probability, percentile

I am throwing one red, one blue and one yellow ball on a grid type table and log each trial. I log the distance of red and blue balls to the yellow one. After 100 trial, i have a historical data and now i calculate probability of yellow ball each time i put them on the table. I am getting percentile using blue-yellow distance and percentile using red-yellow distance. Of course both of them gives different results. I am not searching for an accurate one but is there a way to come up with one result instead of two?

Let's say red-yellow tells me 75th percentile is going to be 105cm from the bottom edge of the table and the blue-yellow tells me 75th percentile is going to be 83cm from the bottom edge of the table.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  I don't understand your question.  What is the "probability of yellow ball," that you are calculating?  What do the red-yellow and blue-yellow distances have to do with the distance from the bottom edge of the table?

Comment: First i throw the red ball and log the distance from bottom edge of the table. After that i throw the blue one and log the same and finally i throw the yellow one and log it and i also update the red and blue one and update the distance between them. I do this 100 times and now i get samples. Now what i do is i throw red one and look at the historical data to calculate where yellow one will land. I do the same for the blue one and i get a percentile score as well. But i want to use both of them to get one result instead of two.